# Is there any way to disable Mac OS X global search string propagation?

Tags: macos, mac, search

Mac OS X has a feature where if you use any search box in any app, it automatically overwrites every other search box with the text you searched.

I find this rarely useful and it often interferes with any workflow where I expect an individual app to stay pre-filled with what I last searched in that app. Is there any way to disable it?

(I've also never seen anyone discuss this feature anywhere. When was it introduced? Does it have a name? Is it mentioned anywhere in the documentation on developer.apple.com?)

Comment: Great question, and I can't believe Apple hasn't worked this out. The usefulness rate of their feature is about 0.0000000001.  I.e. I almost never want it, but it gets in the way of my work flow, as you described.  (I hope someone from Apple sees this!)

Answer (score 2):

It's usually called the find pasteboard or find clipboard, and I think it has been around since before OS X.

I tried [using strings to search in frameworks](https://superuser.com/q/455755/69039), but I didn't find any hidden preferences for making it application-specific.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me find out it's known as NSFindPboard and appears to have existed since early versions of NextSTEP. Still no closer to figuring out how to disable or control it...

Comment: I haven't used it but I just came across https://github.com/mpak/DisableSearchSharing which looks like an alpha-level project to disable it on a per application basis (i.e. DO NOT try to override the global macOS behavior with this not-quite-stable build).